# Explanation of supersonic flow differences between a 2D wedge and a 3D cone

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-dynamics, shock

I know that in case of wedge we have a 2D behavior which creates a discontinuity across the shock, but I am unable to understand why this discontinuity is not present in the case of a conical surface. I have a vague idea that the continuity equation ensures this as, due to increase in the flow area, the velocity must increase.

But still it would be great help if I could get a proper explanation, I couldn't find one in books and net.

I would also like to know which 2D constraints are actually relieved which causes the 3D relaxation effect.

[image]

**EDIT:-** I think i need to reiterate the question, I wanted to ask why does the supersonic flow bend toward the surface in case of being obstructed by a cone unlike in case of wedge, and as per its reasoning i have also read that the flow is more **free** in case of cone, due to presence of 3 dimensions, commonly known as 3D relaxation, so it would be nice if someone could comment upon it too.

[image]

Comment: Really vague and unclear question. Could you edit it to explain all the context? Without the comments it could even be asking about hammering a spike into wood/concrete.

Comment: With your edit, what do you mean by "bend toward the surface"? Both the wedge and the cone are "bending" in a very similar way at the shock front. Are you asking why one is drawn as straight lines (wedge) and one has some curves (cone)?

Comment: yes exactly, thats what i want to know, why parallel in one case and not in other.

Comment: I think the best way to get a "heuristic" understanding is to jump over to [Nasa] (http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/k-12/airplane/shock.html). They have a nice simulator which solves the equations for you and does not only draw stream lines but also rays (which are the answer to your question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this question is complicated since the flow is fundamentally different.

When supersonic flow hits a **wedge** it is abruptly turned by one *oblique shock*. After this all streamlines are parallel since in this 2D-flow-scenario the geometry/flow-area does not change anymore.

When supersonic flow (think of a stream tube/cylinder) hits a **cone** a differential volume element of the stream tube will constantly increase in size while it follows the cone surface. This changes the pressure and is called *relaxation*. Due to this volume increase of the stream tube the **cone flow** has two features/regimes which the **wedge flow** cannot have:

1. The stream lines after the shock are curved (bent) so that they align with the cone geometry.
2. Certain flow-settings will result in a *sonic-line* within the flow downstream of the shock. This means that the supersonic flow after the oblique shock is decelerated until it is subsonic see figure below taken from [Naca Report 1242](http://naca.central.cranfield.ac.uk/reports/1955/naca-report-1242.pdf).

   [image: Naca Report 1242]